# HtmlAgilityPack - how to get Innerhtml value in function{}

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a website which has Following html lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
          set_rate()
});
function set_rate() {
    var rate_f = "1";
    $('#rate_c').html("1.10");
    $('#rate_g').html("7.00");
    $('#time').html("23/08/2021 Evening 02:31 PM");
}
```

I have no knowledge of html so I am lost at pointing HtmlAgilityPack to correct node.

I am trying to get `$('#rate_c').html("1.10");` value 1.10,
`$('#rate_g').html("7.00");` value 7.00 and
`$('#time').html("23/08/2021 Evening 02:31 PM");` value 23/08/2021 Evening 02:31 PM

I am not trying to get values the function gives after running JavaScript, lucky for me the html has the value I am looking for.

Comment: You are using Jquery. Then the  `.html()` function get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements and doesn’t accept any parameter.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj The jQuery [`.html( htmlString )`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) function with a string parameter "sets the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: From [Parsing HTML to get script variable value](https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/18156795/parsing-html-to-get-script-variable-value), you could use `Dim script = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(Function(n) n.Name = "script").First().InnerText`. Then you just have the problem of parsing the JavaScript.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, obviosly, that’s true BUT, in relation with the question **“how to get Innerhtml value”**  does `.html()` needs/accept parameters to achieve what OP needs??

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj The first part of the question was "I am lost at pointing HtmlAgilityPack to correct node." I haven't got time to write an answer including the parsing part right now.

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack` can read only static html. It can't execute javascript.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Once the OP has the JavaScript, they can parse it to get the key-value pairs out of the lines of the form `$('#rate_c').html("1.10")`, where the key starts with "#" and the value is in quotes in the "html("")" part.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You got what I am trying to do, Thanks for your suggested solution I will work on that direction, appreciate the help.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, I am just trying to get value from static HTML where the function is coded and not the value of Jquery of the function. I am lucky to have the value I want in target Static Html code.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Yep I am looking at static html and I am not trying to get value of javascript, just the code part of javascript.

Comment: In that case, you need to get the appropriate script tag, then do string parsing the usual C#/VB way.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I used `Dim script = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(Function(n) n.Name = "script")` and located xpath for the script `//html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/script[3]/@type[1]` used it  like this `Dim script = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/script[3]/@type[1]").InnerText` and got the string value. Thanks for the Help, Now struggling to parse it, any help on what tool I should use. Your Solution really Helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments in chat, you can try doing this:

```
Dim result = New With {.rate_c = "", .rate_g = "", .time = ""}

Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
doc.Load("C:\Temp\test.html")

Dim scriptNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script")
For Each scriptNode In scriptNodes
    If scriptNode.InnerHtml.Contains("$('#rate_c').html(") Then
        result.rate_c = scriptNode.InnerHtml.Substring(scriptNode.InnerHtml.IndexOf("$('#rate_c').html(") + "$('#rate_c').html(".Length + 1)
        result.rate_c = result.rate_c.Substring(0, result.rate_c.IndexOf(""""))
    End If
    If scriptNode.InnerHtml.Contains("$('#rate_g').html(") Then
        result.rate_g = scriptNode.InnerHtml.Substring(scriptNode.InnerHtml.IndexOf("$('#rate_g').html(") + "$('#rate_g').html(".Length + 1)
        result.rate_g = result.rate_g.Substring(0, result.rate_g.IndexOf(""""))
    End If

    '--- ... similarly get other values here ...

Next

'-- lets see what we got!
MessageBox.Show($"rate_c={ result.rate_c}    rate_g={result.rate_g}")
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much this worked like charm. I also learned WITH object

Comment: just curious `Dim result = New With` intellisense says its AnonymousType a. Initially I thought it was a dictionary object, any article you can point where I can learn more about this.

Comment: Yes, it's anonymous type since we are defining it at runtime and there is no way for CLR to know about it before hand. I usually use it to do quick dirty stuff. You can go with a full class definition or separate variables if you want to.

Comment: Nice, a lot to learn for me Thank you for your help